# Cypress intercept not intercepting cy.request

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a Cypress interceptor in `cypress/support/e2e.js` file set to intercept all requests. It works for `cy.visit` calls but it's not triggered for `cy.request` ones. What may be a reason of that? Am I using it in a right way? I'm using Cypress 11.2.0.

```
// cypress/support/e2e.js

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.intercept('*', req => {
    console.log(req.url, req)
  })
})
```

```
// file with tests

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.visit('/some-page') // this works, request is intercepted
})

it('check links', () => {
  cy.get("a").each(a => {
    cy.request(a.prop('href')) // this doesn't work, request is not intercepted
  })
})
```

I read through the Cypress docs but couldn't find any mentioning about distinct treatment of `cy.visit` and `cy.request` in context of `cy.intercept`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't read the documentation closely enough.

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#cy-intercept

> `cy.request()` sends requests to actual endpoints, bypassing those defined using `cy.intercept()`

Comment: Thank you possum. I obviously missed that detail.